# How to declare const in class function

Tags: php, constants

I'm new to php.
I'm having a weird scenario where I cannot declare the following inside a function:

```
const CONST_Example = 1/192;
```

I'v tried also:

```
const CONST_Example  = 1;
```

Do not work either.
I want to be able to save constant float number which is a result of arithmetic expression such as 1/190, etc.

Comment: U should declare it as a class constant and not inside a class method. As naming convention, constants are full camelcase named

Comment: Why is this weird? The documentation says that constants can only be declared at the class level, not in functions.

Comment: Try using `define` if you want to set a named constant at runtime equal to the result of some operation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php for the documentation on class constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed impossible to create that value as a class constant in PHP. You can't declare it like this:

```
class Foo {

    const CONST_Example = 1/192;

}
```

because PHP is not able to *evaluate* expressions while it parses class declarations.
You can also not add the constant to the class after the fact at runtime.

Your options are:

1. Declare it as regular runtime defined constant:

   ```
   define('CONST_Example', 1/192);
   ```
2. Use the next best float representation as a literal:

   ```
   class Foo {

       const CONST_Example = 0.005208333333333333;

   }
   ```

Comment: Note that PHP 5.7 will allow basic evaluation of constants, but you'll have to wait a little while for that

Comment: Note constant expressions made it into PHP 5.6. However, this still won't help with the question of declaring a constant inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

The first one won't work, but the second one should. Here's an example how you can have your class working with constants

```
<?php
class Foo {
    const CONST_EXAMPLE = 1;
}
```

The first one won't work, because of the following reason:

**"The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, a result of a mathematical operation, or a function call."**

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Comment: He said in his question where he's declaring the constant: in a _function_. As you showed, they can only be declared at class level.

Comment: Ok what about defining const to 1/125 for example compiler doesn't like the operator "\"

Comment: That won't work. As I said it musn't be a result of a mathematical operatin, which this would be. :)

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to defining constants using define(), constants defined using the **const** keyword must be declared at the top-level scope because they are defined at compile-time. **This means that they cannot be declared inside functions, loops, if statements or try/catch blocks**.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35381298)